# Read multiple strings until newline character in C

Tags: c, string

I want to make a piece of code that reads strings until `'\n'` is present (it will not save it).
After reading the first string, let's say `"And then none"` I want it to read `"Today"`.
The problem is that what I get is this: `"Todaythen none"`.
I cannot delete the first thing I inserted.

This is my code:

```
for(j=1; j<=num; j++){

        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        c=getchar();
        k=0;
        while(c!='\n'){
            *(title+k)=c;
            c=getchar();
            k++;
        }
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &downloads);

        insertText(&current->anAuthor->text, title, downloads);
        strcpy(title, "");

    }
```

Comment: Use `unget(c, stdin)`;

Comment: That code will fail if it hits `EOF` before the linefeed. Also, make sure `c` is `int` when you add the test for `EOF`.

Comment: @unwind it will not hit EOF as the number of lines to be read are declared at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Addressing code that is out of the snippet you give us is not very helpful(insertText line). I can assume that your string is being overwritten because of some problems with the insertText.

Comment: @ThunderGr only `strcmp` and `strcpy` use `title` inside `insertText`.

Comment: Yes, but it appears that it starts copying from the beginning of the title each time. You should check the pointer location for the start of each string.

Comment: OK, my mistake. I misunderstood the question. What you want is to delete the title string each time you read a new string. You should be able to do this if you add a '\0' at the end of the string you copy in the "insertText" function. You are probably forgetting to do that.

Comment: I used `memset(title,0,k);` after the `insertText` function and it worked.

Comment: Ah, OK, you fill all the size of title with 0. I get what your problem was. You are missing the '\0' by one position, most likely. strcpy(title,"") does a title[0]='\0', leaving the other characters in place. You should recheck your code.

Comment: Detail: You do not want "reads strings until '\n'".  In C a "string" is an array of `char` up to and including a terminating `'\0'`.  Instead you want "read groups of `char` separated by `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to zero-terminate the string after writing to it, what you now get is a mixture of the old and the new string. For example, add `title[k] = '\0'` after the `while` loop.

Also, your current code doesn't make sure that `k` doesn't exceed the allocated size of `title`, which is a [lurking buffer overflow bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added `title[k] = '\0'`. My debugger shows that after getting into the `while` loop for the second time, `title` gets from `""` to the previous value it had in the first loop.

Comment: @user3229330 I don't see how it could magically obtain the previous value. Are you following the loop through to the end? The "old value" might be observable before the loop finishes, setting up new contents and the new terminator.

Comment: @user3229330 Hmm...Where does the "getchar()" read from in the while loop? Setting title to "" *after* the while loop could do the trick.

Comment: @user4815162342 this magically appearing previous value is a mystery. However, this is what the Xcode debugger showed me.

Comment: @user3229330 You still didn't say *when* Xcode is showing this value. If you are looking at it when the loop begins, you will see the temporary state of the string, which can be as you described because the previous string characters are still present in memory.

Comment: The problem is, most likely, with title indexing. Since memset(title,0,k) worked, there must be a shift in the start of title somewhere.