# I have problem using scanf() to get a newline if the newline came after a whitespace

Tags: c, scanf, newline

I wanted to be able to store an array of strings. And the way I was doing it is with loop. I get each sting with scanf the have a get char to get the white space and check if it's a newline break the loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%50s", arrayofStrings[i]);

        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n') break;
    }
```

This works in most cases. But if I have something like "I am " with a space before the end of the string it will not get to the newline.

I tried to add a while loop to skip any " " but it doesn't work as I wanted it to.

The expected result is that if I type "I am \n" it will still get to the new line and break the loop and just ignores the whitespace.

---

I change my code after the suggestions on the comments.

```
char cha[500];
int index= 0;

    fgets(cha, 500, stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            if (cha[j] != ' ' && cha[index] != '\0') {
                var[i][j] = cha[index];
                index++;
            }
            else {
                action[i][j] = '\0';

                index++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (cha[index] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }

    action[strlen(*action)] = "\0";
    printf("%s", var[0]);
```

if I write "Nobody is here"

var[0] will have Nobody.

But when I check with `strcmp(var[0], "Nobody")`, they appear not to be equal.

Comment: The `%s` format (no matter specified field width) reads space-delimited "words". If you want to read a while line use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: I dont want to read I want to stop reading when I hit enter

Comment: Think about that for a while... You want to read until you hit `Enter` which ends the current line. And `fgets` read a line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116246/read-multiple-strings-until-newline-character-in-c this might help

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed my code using fgets() please refer to the edit on the post. Now I am having a different problem.

Comment: fgets reads newline character in the buffer. See [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: How do I fix it ?  Nobody is in the middle of the string so it shoudn't be affected by the new line

Comment: You don't null-terminate `var[i]`. And you don't need to dynamically allocate `char`, make it an array.

Comment: I changed my code and added the null at the end but same problem

Comment: Can you clarity what is the problem - provide some code to replicate the problem. The note about 'strcmp' is not clear

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invent an oval wheel when round wheels are already around... The C library exists for a reason: to avoid programmers to waste time in common but tedious tasks.

Here you want:

- read a line of text, ended with a newline: ok `fgets` is the way to go
- split the line on spaces `sscanf` can be used or `strspn` - `strcspn`. The one to use depends on your actual use case: `sscanf` is better if you want to extract a given number of tokens, `strspn` - `strcspn` is more powerful is you have a large line and want to avoid to use twice the memory for the tokens.

Of course, it is always possible to parse *by hand*, and we used it a lot when only `strtok` was available. Simply you must keep away from the keyboard for a while, take a paper sheet and a pencil and calmly describe what you really need. Then try it (still on the paper) for various inputs, looking for possible corner cases. When it works (on paper) **and only then** convert the algorithm in C language, and test the identified corner cases under a debugger. If you want to produce professional grade code, write down test cases for the normal use case and the corner case. If you later make changes to your code, the test will immediately show the possible regressions.

You current code (and the lack of comments) shows that you have written it down without really thinking about what it will really do.

Here is a possible pseudo-code for the parsing:

```
Loop over the line one char at a time
  if in a word
    if a word character
      add the character to current word
    if a separator
      end the current word with a null
  if in separators
    if a word character
      add a new word and make it the current word
      add the character to that word
if in a word
  end the word with a null character
```

I know there are a lot of tests and you have to know whether you are in a word or not, but at least it should work...